# how to get a field value from more than 7 tables using where condition

Tags: sql

I have a flat file which consists of a list of mobile numbers and their status as active or inactive.So my job is to write a SQL query such that i need to fetch a list of 7 tables for a particular msisdn and i have to get the status of the msisdn.So any suggestion how to write.

I cannot use joins.

Comment: Give us something to work with... schema, sample data, desired result, [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)...

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? What is the table schemas like? What have you trie? UNION?

Comment: i have to write script which has to check for the msisdns that are active and inactive and has to display them as which are active and which are inactive.but the msisdn will be present in only any one of the tables;

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you will be using `UNION` on this.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT mobileNo, moileStatus FROM table1
    UNION 
    SELECT mobileNo, moileStatus FROM table2
    UNION 
    SELECT mobileNo, moileStatus FROM table3
    UNION 
    SELECT mobileNo, moileStatus FROM table4
    UNION 
    SELECT mobileNo, moileStatus FROM table5
    UNION
    SELECT mobileNo, moileStatus FROM table6
    UNION 
    SELECT mobileNo, moileStatus FROM table7
) allMobile
WHERE allMobile.mobileNo = '' 
      -- OR something like that
```

Comment: how to check with a where condition for a particluar msisdn using the above query

Comment: @user1345837 wrap it in a subquery and to the filtering outside, chec mu updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Do A [BULK INSERT to Load the Text File](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-bulk-insert-to-load-a-text-file)

Step 2: Fetch Records from all the tables for a particular `msisdn`

Step 3: Join between Step 1 and Step 2 for a particular `msisdn`

**Pseudo Code**

```
CREATE TABLE TempTable
(
 MSISDN INT,
 MobileNumber VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
 TheStatus varchar (10) NOT NULL
)

--Step 1: 
BULK INSERT TempTable FROM 'D:\InputMobileNumbers.txt' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '","') 

-- Step 2:
INSERT INTO #TEMP 
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT MSISDN,MobileNumber FROM Table1 WHERE MSISDN = @MSISDN UNION All
SELECT MSISDN,MobileNumber FROM Table2 WHERE MSISDN = @MSISDN UNION All
.............................................................................
.............................................................................
SELECT MSISDN,MobileNumber FROM Table7 WHERE MSISDN = @MSISDN UNION All
)X

-- Step 3
SELECT tt.MSISDN,tt.MobileNumber,tt.TheStatus
FROM TempTable tt
JOIN #TEMP t ON tt.MSISDN = t.MSISDN
WHERE tt.MSISDN = @MSISDN


DROP TABLE #TEMP
DROP TABLE TempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.column1,t1.column2,...,t2.column4,..
from table1 t1 
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.column1=t2.column3
left outer join table2 t3 on t2.column1=t3.column2
.....
where t1.active=1 and t2.column2>0 ....
order by t1.column1,.....
```